# React Native Android: Always one instance of the app?

Tags: android, react-native

Suppose I have one instance of my app already running, when opening a URI, android doesn't use the running instance, instead it runs a new instance of the app. It really hurts me. How can I fix this?

*I'm using **React Native**. As far as I know React Native always uses **one single activity**, so I have only one activity in my app, I thought it might be helpful.*

Comment: Do you have an Intent filter for your app? And I'm not too sure that React Native only uses one Activity

Comment: Yes, I have the filter but I'm pretty sure React Native uses only one activity.